# Why does only one of my Riot.js tags render?

Tags: javascript, html, web, riot.js

I have a relatively simple page which loads Riot.js from a CDN, RiotControl from a local script file, a `Store` for RiotControl from a file, and two custom tags `custom-a` and `custom-b`.

```
    <div class="ui text container" id="context">
        <form class="ui form">
            <h1>A Descriptive and Lovely Header</h1>

            <div class="ui divider"></div>

            <custom-a/>

            <p>this is just a paragraph</p>
            <custom-b/>
        </form>
    </div>

    <!-- Riot.js Ceremony -->
    <script>
        RiotControl.addStore(new Store());
        riot.mount('*');
    </script>
```

The tags are being mounted -- `console.log` lines in the two tag files show that -- and events are being routed correctly (once again proven via `console.log`). However, nothing after the first custom tag renders: `custom-a` shows up if it's on top, and `custom-b` shows up if it's on top, but the `<p>` between them does not render and the other doesn't render if it's in there.

I thought that it might be some issue with the CSS, so I removed the Semantic UI links from the page, but that makes no difference besides style.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It´s not a Riot issue, it´s the way the browser renders self-closing tags. Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9uezdbo9/1/

before

```
<div>Element before</div>
<self-close/>
<div>Element after</div>
```

rendered

```
<div>Element before</div>
<self-close>
  <div>Element after</div>
</self-close>
```

ref: https://github.com/riot/riot/issues/1111 check GianlucaGuarini answer

Answer (score 0):

It ends up being amazingly simple: the "compile-on-the-fly" aspect of Riot.js doesn't seem to deal well with self-closing tags. This works fine:

```
<custom-a></custom-a>
<custom-b></custom-b>
```